# ViewModel object difference

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

What is difference in use ViewModel in Fragment between:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModelClass::class.java)
```

and

```
viewModel = activity?.let { ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is called from an Activity or Fragment and passes itself as the owner of the ViewModel. The second looks like it is called from a Fragment that wants to use its attached activity as the owner of the ViewModel. And the author seems to be `!!`-averse to the point of using `?.let` even at a stage of the lifecycle where `activity` is known to be not null. The code could be changed to

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

or

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(activity!!).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

Presumably, you wouldn't call this while `activity` is null. You usually get your ViewModel at start-up, not in some callback.

`requireActivity()` will give you a more-informative exception than `activity!!` if you use it incorrectly, though in practice it would be pretty easy to see what the issue is if you are familiar with the Fragment lifecycle.

But all of the above are unnecessary now that the Jetpack library includes the `viewModels()` property delegate. You can get the view model at the property declaration site without making it a `var`:

```
val viewModel by viewModels<MainActivityViewModel>()
```

Comment: Thanks man! Now I understeand the difference. One more thing, In normal use, without comunication between Fragments, is it better to use Fragment Owner or use the Activity?

Comment: Presumably if the ViewModel only contains data that is not shared with other Fragments, it should be local to that Fragment.